# Compare Rows To Make Noun Chunk in PySpark

Tags: pyspark

I have a Spark dataframe where each row is the token from a sentence and includes its part of speech. I am trying to find the best way to compare one row to the next in order to create the longest noun chunk.

```
+------+-----------+---------------------------+--------+-------+-------+-----+
|REV_ID|    SENT_ID|                   SENTENCE|TOKEN_ID|  TOKEN|  LEMMA|  POS|
+------+-----------+---------------------------+--------+-------+-------+-----+
|     1|          1|Ice hockey game took hours.|       1|    Ice|    ice| NOUN|
|     1|          1|Ice hockey game took hours.|       2| hockey| hockey| NOUN|
|     1|          1|Ice hockey game took hours.|       3|   game|   game| NOUN|
|     1|          1|Ice hockey game took hours.|       4|   took|   take| VERB|
|     1|          1|Ice hockey game took hours.|       5|  hours|   hour| NOUN|
```

I know a for loop isn't efficient but I'm not sure how else to get my intended results like below:

```
+------+-----------+---------------------------+--------+-------+-------+-----+----------------+
|REV_ID|    SENT_ID|                   SENTENCE|TOKEN_ID|  TOKEN|  LEMMA|  POS|      NOUN_CHUNK|
+------+-----------+---------------------------+--------+-------+-------+-----+----------------+
|     1|          1|Ice hockey game took hours.|       1|    Ice|    ice| NOUN| ice hockey game|
|     1|          1|Ice hockey game took hours.|       2| hockey| hockey| NOUN| ice hockey game|
|     1|          1|Ice hockey game took hours.|       3|   game|   game| NOUN| ice hockey game|
|     1|          1|Ice hockey game took hours.|       4|   took|   take| VERB|            NULL|
|     1|          1|Ice hockey game took hours.|       5|  hours|   hour| NOUN|            hour|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with window functions.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w=Window().partitionBy("SENT_ID").orderBy("TOKEN_ID")
w1=Window().partitionBy("SENT_ID", "list")

df\
  .withColumn("list", F.sum(F.when(F.col("POS")=='NOUN', F.lit(0)).otherwise(F.lit(1))).over(w))\
  .withColumn("list", F.expr("""IF(POS!='NOUN',null,list)"""))\
  .withColumn("NOUN_CHUNK", F.when(F.col("list").isNotNull(),F.array_join(F.collect_list("LEMMA").over(w1),' '))\
                             .otherwise(F.lit(None))).drop("list").orderBy("SENT_ID","TOKEN_ID").show()

#+------+-------+--------------------+--------+------+------+----+---------------+
#|REV_ID|SENT_ID|            SENTENCE|TOKEN_ID| TOKEN| LEMMA| POS|     NOUN_CHUNK|
#+------+-------+--------------------+--------+------+------+----+---------------+
#|     1|      1|Ice hockey game t...|       1|   Ice|   ice|NOUN|ice hockey game|
#|     1|      1|Ice hockey game t...|       2|hockey|hockey|NOUN|ice hockey game|
#|     1|      1|Ice hockey game t...|       3|  game|  game|NOUN|ice hockey game|
#|     1|      1|Ice hockey game t...|       4|  took|  take|VERB|           null|
#|     1|      1|Ice hockey game t...|       5| hours|  hour|NOUN|           hour|
#+------+-------+--------------------+--------+------+------+----+---------------+
```

Comment: I tried implementing this but it seems to only return tokens that are NOT nouns and therefore all nulls for NOUN_CHUNK

Comment: @user3242036 double check ur code, it works fine on my cluster, or provide more data to show that it doesnt work as described

Comment: The only thing I changed was the addition of "REV_ID" to the window partitionBy functions

Comment: i see but that wouldnt change the functioning of the code tho. i tried with more data and it works perfectly. provide more data cases where its not working

Comment: I'm seeing strange behavior that I've never seen before. Sometimes it will return exactly what you show and what I'm expecting. Other times it returns an empty data frame. I'm changing nothing except pressing run again

Comment: But I think that's my own issue. Thanks so much for your help. I've spent way too long pondering this and this was very helpful